# Getting the current url on the client side in next.js

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js

So I am working on a nodejs app which I will have my new website on and I want to make a way for my user on the clientside to display different things, re-renderd depending on what the user is pressing on. My idea is that for example firstly the user would see "Please select a tool first" and then the user will select a tool in the navbar which then the page will be re-renderd and display the tool selected inside a jumbotron with the url being changed for example then /admin/[ToolSelected].

The only thing is tho that I do not know how to achieve this. I was thinking that the client side code could detect what the url is and is placed as a page variable then the tool will displayed with a IF statement depending on what the page variable is.

**Would my theory work or how can a achieve this in an efficient way?**

Here is my main page code:

```
// Including Navbar and css
import AdminLayout from '../comps/admin/adminLayout'

// the so called "tools" more will exist in the future
import Passform from '../comps/admin/tools/passform'


// Fetching the current url the user is on
var page = CURRENT_URL;


const jumbotron = {
  background: 'white'
}

const Admin = (page) => (

  <AdminLayout>

  <style global jsx>
  {
    `body {
      background: #eff0f3;
    }`
  }
  </style>
    <div className="jumbotron" style={jumbotron}>

    {(page == "passform") ? (
      <Passform/>
    ) : (
      <h3>Something is wrong :/ . {page}</h3>
    )}

    </div>
  </AdminLayout>
)

export default Admin
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can wrap your component with [`withRouter`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#withrouter) HOC, that will inject the `router` object, that has current `pathname`.

```
import { withRouter } from 'next/router';

const Admin = ({ router }) => (
  <AdminLayout>
    <style global jsx>
      {`
        body {
          background: #eff0f3;
        }
      `}
    </style>
    <div className="jumbotron" style={jumbotron}>
      {router.pathname == 'passform' ? <Passform /> : <h3>Something is wrong :/ . {page}</h3>}
    </div>
  </AdminLayout>
);

export default withRouter(Admin);
```

### Using Hooks

If you prefer hooks you can use [`useRouter`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#userouter) hook.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const Admin = () => {
const router = useRouter();

return (
  <AdminLayout>
    <style global jsx>
      {`
        body {
          background: #eff0f3;
        }
      `}
    </style>
    <div className="jumbotron" style={jumbotron}>
      {router.pathname == 'passform' ? <Passform /> : <h3>Something is wrong :/ . {page}</h3>}
    </div>
  </AdminLayout>);
};

export default Admin;
```

`router.pathname` will contain the "config" url, therefore for dynamic routes, it will contain the `[paramName]` parts.

### Dynamic routes

You can check the [`router.query`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#example) for the existing of the dynamic part.

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

// assume that your dynamic route us `/static/[dynamicPart]`

const Admin = () => {
const router = useRouter();

return (
  <AdminLayout>
    <style global jsx>
      {`
        body {
          background: #eff0f3;
        }
      `}
    </style>
    <div className="jumbotron" style={jumbotron}>
      {router.query.dynamicPart == 'passform' ? <Passform /> : <h3>Something is wrong :/ . {page}</h3>}
    </div>
  </AdminLayout>);
};

export default Admin;
```

Comment: I think you want `import {withRouter } from 'next/router';`

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvotes? `import {withRouter} from 'next/router';` is now part of the answer. That along with `export default withRouter(Admin);` worked great. PS. React inspector was a quick way to check.

Comment: Downvoting because this is not a usable example, removes some of the details from the question which makes this more clear, and lacks depth in explanation about what is actually happening here.

Comment: I’ve changed the implementation to use router.pathname

Comment: when i do that for a dynamic route it ends up being a url like `/mypage/[slug]`. Anyone know how i can get the value of the slug? i.e. the actual URL

Comment: @ConnorLeech, I've added a section for dynamic routes

Answer (score 3):

## NextJS 13 with the AppDir router

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-pathname

```js
'use client'
 
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function ExampleClientComponent() {
  const pathname = usePathname()
  return <p>Current pathname: {pathname}</p>
}
```