# How do i highlight current page in the nav-menu? I'm using next link and antd layout component with a sider

Tags: navigation, next.js, antd, highlight

I'm using nextjs Link and a antd layout component to design my navigation pane. I want to highlight the nav menu item whenever I'm on a specific page.How do i achieve this?
[code for my navigation menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4DHw.png)

Comment: Please do _not_ use images for code. Add any relevant code as a code snippet to your question.

Comment: Get the page's URL path (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58022046/get-url-pathname-in-nextjs) and check it against the Link href in a ternary statement. Like the CSS className would be `pagePath == Link.href ? highlighted : not-highlighted`

Answer (score 0):

For future people looking at a quick answer:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
```

In your menu component:

```
const router = useRouter()
const [current, setCurrent] = useState(router.pathname);
useEffect ( () => {
  setCurrent(router.pathname)
}, [router.pathname])
```

Then the antd menu item:

```
<Menu
  selectedKeys={[current]}
  items={items}
/>
```