# NextJS - Get dynamic variable in getStaticProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, next.js

So I have getStaticProps and need to do some data fetching based on a variable here is an example

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch(localWordpressUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: `
        query AllPostsQuery {
          posts(where: {categoryName: "blog"}) {
            nodes {
              slug
              content
              title
            }
          }
        }
      `,
    })
  });

  const json = await res.json();
  return {
    props: {
      posts: json.data.posts,
    }
  };
}
```

Where categoryName: "blog" needs to be a variable instead of hard coded.  I know you can get the slug, but what I need is before the slug. i.e. site.com/blog/slug.  Any suggestions on this?

Comment: where does the variable come from?

Comment: either the url or if possible I could pass it in, but im following the [slug].js convention so the issue is that component is getting "called" from <Link href="/blog/id" />

Comment: Using getStaticProps you can only get the `params,defaultLocale,locale,locales` and not the whole url

Comment: is it possible to pass in some variable here from a parent? getStaticProps(context, "someVar")

Comment: No I don't think you can pass any second parameter. There is nothing mentioned in the docs regarding this

Comment: Any suggestion on a fix to my problem.  Basically I have a /blog and a /photos.  both are using the Link component to render [slug].js <Link href={`/posts/${post.slug}`}>{post.title}</Link>.  In theory I would like to display other posts inside of [slug].js that are in the same category.  Currently I have no way of knowing the category.

Comment: `display other posts inside of [slug].js that are in the same category` I didn't understand this part. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score -2):

You're actually really close. What you need is to grab the context out of your `getStaticProps` function. Add this to your `getStaticProps` function, and look at the `console log` to see what's happening.

```js
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(context, null, 3));

  const { asPath, req, res, pathname, query } = context;
  if (req) {
    let localWordpressURL = req.headers.host;
    console.log(localWordpressURL);
  }
}
```

Comment: so only thing I get out of that is the 
"params: { slug: "/slug" }

Comment: context object is different for getStaticProps and getServerSideProps

Comment: Correct. My oversight. Please see answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58022046/get-url-pathname-in-nextjs