# How can I get the url pathname on a server component next js 13

Tags: javascript, next.js, path, router, react-server-components

So basically I have a server component in app dir and I want to get the pathname. I tried to do it using window.location but it does not work.
Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: I don't think window exists on the serverside. Consider using the path module and dirname?

Comment: I already know that window does not exists, but thanks anyways

Comment: found some info on answer by @and-yet-it-compiles in documentation "Using cookies() or headers() in a Server Component will opt the whole route into dynamic rendering at request time." source: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/static-and-dynamic-rendering

Comment: just add {params} to the server function and you will get the pathname.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This works for me

```js
import { headers } from "next/headers";

const headersList = headers();
const domain = headersList.get("x-forwarded-host") || "";
const protocol = headersList.get("x-forwarded-proto") || "";
const pathname = headersList.get("x-invoke-path") || "";
```

Comment: Search params are missing when use this approach

Comment: This no longer work in v14.0.2. What version are you using?

Answer (score 29):

Alternatively, I think an even easier solution would be to use Next's headers already present in the request, like `host` or `refer`.

Example:

```
import { headers } from 'next/headers';

export default function Navbar() {
    const headersList = headers();
    const domain = headersList.get('host') || "";
    const fullUrl = headersList.get('referer') || "";

    console.log(fullUrl);
}
```

Comment: `referer` is the URL that you came from, not the URL of the page you're on.

Answer (score 26):

Take a look at https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43704 , pauliusuza solved this issue

You can do a workaround using a middleware

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(request: Request) {

  // Store current request url in a custom header, which you can read later
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
  requestHeaders.set('x-url', request.url);

  return NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      // Apply new request headers
      headers: requestHeaders,
    }
  });
}
```

Then use it from inside of a root layout:

```
import { headers } from 'next/headers';

export default function RootLayout() {
  const headersList = headers();
  // read the custom x-url header
  const header_url = headersList.get('x-url') || "";
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: One caveat here though. This will completely disable SSG for the page. More information could be found 
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/static-and-dynamic-rendering.

Comment: In my case, I got the pathname using the `x-invoke-path` header

Comment: I get null logged for header_url

Comment: ATTENTION : doesn't work in production i iis I don't know about others like linux or ...

Comment: This doesn't work for the **root layout** after an in-page navigation. For example, if we directly go to `http://localhost:3000/fa` it works. But if then we navigate to `/en` page (e.g. by clicking on `<Link href='/en' ...`) the middleware works, but the layout component doesn't rerender!

Answer (score 18):

NextJS v14 Serverside get Pathname

```
 import { headers } from "next/headers";

 const heads = headers()

 const pathname = heads.get('next-url')
```

**Heads-up**: it might have performance implications. From the NextJS documentation:

> **Good to know**:
>
> headers() is a Dynamic Function whose returned values cannot be known
> ahead of time. Using it in a layout or page will opt a route into
> dynamic rendering at request time.

[About dynamic rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#dynamic-rendering)

**Important!** The VP of Product @vercel [discourages the use of the next-url header](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/57762#issuecomment-1802052863)

Comment: Thank you sir. My use case was to dynamically change the styling based on the pathName

Comment: In Nextjs v14.0.2. this header is not available. See https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/58542

Comment: @alisahindev I do not understand the comment. But the header `next-url` is no longer supported.

Comment: next 14.0.4 and it's working just fine @nordic70

Comment: I'm also on next 14.0.4 and while I have seen the `next-url` header sometimes, it is not working reliably. Not in dev mode and not in production on vercel.

Comment: This was discouraged by the VP of Vercel. [See here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/57762#issuecomment-1802052863)

Comment: Why is it discouraged? Maybe it should not be used in certain scenarios - while being OK to use in other scenarios

Answer (score 4):

create a middleware.ts in the src dir of your app, it would be responsible for urls of your application, i added some other useful properties such as origin which is good for calling internal api and the pathname for accessing the path of your component;
note that it only can be used inside server component

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(request: Request) {

const url = new URL(request.url);
const origin = url.origin;
const pathname = url.pathname;
const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
requestHeaders.set('x-url', request.url);
requestHeaders.set('x-origin', origin);
requestHeaders.set('x-pathname', pathname);

return NextResponse.next({
    request: {
        headers: requestHeaders,
    }
});
}
```

and in your server components use it like

```js
import { headers } from "next/headers";

export default async function page() {

    const headersList = headers()
    const header_url = headersList.get('x-url') || "";
    const pathname = headersList.get('x-pathname');
    const origin_url = headersList.get('x-origin');

}
```

based on https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43704

Answer (score 3):

This finds the pathname assuming you got a referer cookie:

```
import { headers } from 'next/headers';

const domain = headersList.get('host') || "";
const fullUrl = headersList.get('referer') || "";
const [,pathname] = fullUrl.match( new RegExp(`https?:\/\/${domain}(.*)`))||[];

console.log(pathname);
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75363135/16390814) is almost correct . Using app directory with src pattern I realized that I need to change the `middleware.ts` placement like the following.

```js
.
├── src
│   ├── app
│   └── middleware.ts
```