# Nextjs Middleware to handle canonical url in Netlify SSR

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13, netlify

I am trying to create canonical url for my pages using next metadata in RootLayout `layout.js` file.

This is what my `middleware.js` looks like

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
export function middleware(request) {
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers)
  const { pathname } = request.nextUrl

  requestHeaders.set('x-url', request.url || '')
  requestHeaders.set('x-invoke-path', pathname || '')

  return NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      headers: requestHeaders
    }
  })
}
```

And in the layout.js file I an trying to get the canonical url as following

```js
...
import { headers } from 'next/headers'
...

export const metadata = () => {
  const headersList = headers()
  const pathName =
     headersList.get('x-url') || headersList.get('x-invoke-path') || ''
  return {
    ...
     alternates: {
      canonical: `https://example.com ${pathName}`
    }
    ....
  }
```

What am I missing here? I am getting the full path as expected in local env though.

Comment: Have you tried the answer of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75362636/how-can-i-get-the-url-pathname-on-a-server-component-next-js-13) ?

Comment: @BenjaminFourgeaud that is exactly what I tried, but I am not getting it in Netlify

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might be an issue with how you're constructing the canonical URL. In your metadata function, you are combining the base URL (https://example.com) with the pathName using a space. Instead, you should use a forward slash (/) to join them together.

```
import { headers } from 'next/headers';


export const metadata = () => {
  const headersList = headers();
  const pathName =
    headersList.get('x-url') || headersList.get('x-invoke-path') || '';
  
  return {
    ...
    alternates: {
      canonical: `https://example.com${pathName}`
    },
    ...
  };
};
```

By replacing the space with a forward slash, you should get the correct canonical URL, combining the base URL and the pathName. This assumes that pathName already includes the leading slash if it's not an empty string. If not, you might need to adjust the logic for constructing the pathName.

Comment: No, my `pathName` is empty

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?