# In next.js server side page component (in the app directory), how do you get the current url?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I am using
next.js version 13.
experimental app directory, which does not have access to getServerSideProps()

Pages in the "app" directory are server side by default.

Inside page.js, I am trying to get the url of the current page.

How would I do that?

```
export default async function myPage(props) {
    const prot =  // HTTP or HTTPS
    const domain = //www.myserver.com
    const port = //3000
    ... and so on.
    
    
}
```

I saw this solution:
[Get URL pathname in nextjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58022046/get-url-pathname-in-nextjs)

But 'next\router' that doesn't work on server components.

I get this error when compiling:
You have a Server Component that imports next/router. Use next/navigation instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your use case is, but I needed to get the current url so I could redirect unauthenticated users to the login page with a `redirectTo` param.

Per the Next.js [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#layouts):

> Layouts do not have access to the current route segment(s)

Instead this can be implemented using [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware):

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {

  if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/protected/path') && userIsUnauthenticated()) {
    const currentUrl = req.nextUrl;
    const redirectTo =
      currentUrl.pathname + currentUrl.search + currentUrl.hash;

    const redirect = new URL('/login', req.url);
    redirect.searchParams.set('redirectTo', redirectTo);
    return NextResponse.redirect(redirect);
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

The key here is [`NextRequest.nextUrl`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-request#nexturl) which

> Extends the native [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) API with additional convenience methods, including Next.js specific properties.

Example:

```js
const protocol = req.nextUrl.protocol // HTTP or HTTPS
const domain = req.nextUrl.hostname // www.myserver.com
const port = req.nextUrl.port // 3000
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option for your page would be to import `next/headers` then do this:

```
const headersList = headers();
const host = headersList.get("host");
const urlPath = headersList.get("next-url");
```